# Loop through a list of names defined in a variable

Tags: linux, bash

```
list="name1 name2 name3 name4"
dir="/test/dir"
for i in $dir/${list};do echo $i;done;
```

I get

```
/test/dir/name1
name2
name3
name4
```

I want

```
/test/dir/name1
/test/dir/name2
/test/dir/name3
/test/dir/name4
```

Note: I currently have a working solution `for i in ${list};do echo $dir/$i;done;` but would like to know why the above command isn't yielding the desired outcome and if there's any tweak to make it work. Thanks

Comment: Your current working solution will break if there are white space involve/included in the value of the assignment, because variables is not quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but would like to know why the above command isn't yielding the desired outcome

The `"$list"` expand as one argument/element

```
list='name1 name2 name3 name4'; printf '<%s>\n' "$list"
```

Output

```
<name1 name2 name3 name4>
```

If you use an array it expands each element separate by `IFS`

```
list=(name1 name2 name3 name4); printf '<%s>\n' "${list[@]}"
```

Output

```
<name1>
<name2>
<name3>
<name4>
```

Using an array for the list.

```bsh
list=(name{1..4})  ##: this expands to name1 name2 name4 because of brace expansion.
dir="/test/dir"

##: prefend "$dir/" in every element in the array list using /#/
for i in "${list[@]/#/"$dir/"}"; do 
  echo "$i"
done
```

Output

```
/test/dir/name1
/test/dir/name2
/test/dir/name3
/test/dir/name4
```

Or if the goal is just to add the path, you can just print directly.

```
printf '%s\n' "${list[@]/#/"$dir/"}"
```

Comment: what if I have something like`list="name1 fileA testB name4"` as supposed to having `list="name1 name2 name3 name4"`

Comment: Right, then don't use brace expansion, `list=(name1 fileA testB name4)`

Comment: Although the `name` can be done with `name{1,4}` and the `file` to `file{A,B}`